# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении, в частности в этом?

Tags: пунктуация

*Сидоров так волновался, идя делать предложение своей девушке, что забыл,
какое.*

Нужна ли запятая после слова «забыл»? По идее там одно слово «какое», ничего распространенного....

Answer (score 2):

**По общему правилу запятая не нужна.**

> Запятая не ставится, если... придаточная часть состоит из одного
> союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): *Я бы тоже
> желал знать почему (Л. Т.); Не знаю почему, но я его не понимал
> (Триф.); Трудно сказать почему; Он ушёл и не сказал куда.*

**Но она может ставиться по желанию автора.**

> В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой или тире и перед
> одиночным союзным словом: *Что же надо делать? Научите, что* — усиленное
> логическое выделение местоимения; *Одно время он что-то шептал, не
> могли понять — что? (А. Т.)* — постановка тире подчеркивает значение
> местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией.

Источник: [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=260).

Comment: Вот-вот...Тоже думала, что не надо... Запятую ставить перед одним словом....